# Why can I single click approve edits to tag wikis I edited earlier?

Tags: support, bug, edits, privileges, tag-wiki

On the emerging IoT.SE which is in private beta I have the privilege to approve tag wikis but have not yet reached the free tag wiki editing privilege. Today another user edited a tag wiki excerpt I edited before. My version was the last and active one. Apparently [my approval](https://iot.stackexchange.com/posts/21/revisions)<sup>1</sup> put that edit into effect.

I have moderator tool access and checked, there was no other person approving that specific edit suggestion. However I am not a moderator, so my vote alone shouldn't be binding, should it?

Is my vote binding because I was somehow the owner of the previous version?

---

<sub>1: The site is in private beta and whoever wants to follow that link likely has to detour via [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94224?phase=beta) to get there.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## It appears so.

On the review, your name is showing up with the highlight, meaning that you are the owner. And owners have single-click approve/reject powers. As for *why* you are the owner... I don't know.

As @Aurora0001 mentioned in the comments, it possibly is because you did create the tag wiki, so the system treats it like Q/A. (Yes, I checked and saw that you were the first person to edit the wiki, so you created it.)

Comment: My guess is that the system sees that @Helmar was the creator and treats it just like a question/answer - the owner gets a binding vote (although I don't know why Community isn't the actual owner).